# How to enable session variables in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, session-variables

Whenever I use session variables in webparts in sharepoint the page doesn't load and i get an error. I was adviced to enable them because they may be disabled. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default the Session State is Disabled in SharePoint. If you look at the Web.Config the you will see that as below.

```
<pages enableSessionState="false"
```

You can enable it there. Else you can Enable this at the Page Level.

Comment: Thanks man, but which Web.Config file exactly should I modify that in?

Comment: Web.Config file of the SharePoint Site that you are Using. Be selective about enabling the Session in the whole application. Because it will be a extra call for the Pages that dont need the Session. So I would advice that you enable only on the Page where you want the Session.

Comment: But still which pages? I mean how can I know those pages on the hard drive? Where are they present and what is its path?

Comment: I am using SmartPart which addes a usercontrol into a webpart in sharepoint.

Comment: I think i found somethign and modified to this but it still makes the same error:

 <pages enableSessionState="true" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" asyncTimeout="7">

Comment: In your Server follow Start->Run->Type InetMgr->Press Enter->You will get Internet Information Server-> Expand the Tree->Find Web Sites->Find your Web Site . Right Click ->Properties -> Select Home Tab->You see a Local Path Navigate to that Path in  the Computer and change that Web Config File

Answer (score 1):

THEN, you must go into your web application and add the same session state module to the IIS7 managed pipeline.

1.Open IIS 7 manager, and find your web application.
2.Double click "Modules" in the IIS section.
3.Click "Add Managed Module..." on the right hand pane.
4.In the Add Managed Module dialog, enter "SessionState" or something like that for the name, and choose the following item from the dropdown:
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

After that, session state should be enabled for your web app/web service!

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify two lines, the first one mentioned by kusek and another one:

**Uncomment the following line:**
`<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />`

**Modify the following line:**
`<pages enableSessionState="true" ….. />`

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add/uncomment the Sessionstate module in your web.config file, under `<system.web><httpModules>`:

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```